# Querying ElasticSearch data collections using PlainElastic QueryBuilder

Tags: c#, collections, elasticsearch

I'm trying to put together a Search page and build JSON in c# using the PlainElastic QueryBuilder functionality.  I have a custom class I built that represents the indexed data.  This data contains collections buried underneath collections which is giving me problems retrieving any data.

Here is my custom class slimmed down for only the properties relevant.  SearchResult is the main parent class.  Names and Role are child classes.

```
 public class SearchResult
  {
   public Names Names {get; set; }
  }

 public class Names
  {
   public String FirstName {get; set; }
   public String LastName {get; set; }
   public Role Role {get; set; }
  }

 public class Role
  {
   public String Id {get; set; }
   public String Name {get; set; }
  }
```

What I'm trying to do is construct the QueryBuilder object to find data based on Parameters of FirstName, LastName, and RoleName.  Here is my initial try at syntax that is providing me zero results:

```
query = new QueryBuilder<SearchResult>()
              .Query(q => q
                  .Bool(b => b
                      .Must(m => m
                          .QueryString(qs => qs
                              .Fields(SearchResult => SearchResult.Names[0].FirstName).Query("John")
                          )
                      )
                     .Must(m => m
                             .QueryString(qs => qs
                                 .Fields(SearchResult => SearchResult.Names[0].LastName).Query("Smith")
                         )
                     )          
                     .Must(m => m
                             .QueryString(qs => qs
                                 .Fields(SearchResult => SearchResult.Names[0].Role.Name).Query("Manager")
                         )          
                    )
                 )
             ).BuildBeautified();
```

I then execute the following to get my results:

```
string result = connection.Post(Commands.Search("records", "record"), query);
SearchResult<SearchResult> objResult = serializer.ToSearchResult<SearchResult>(result);
```

If I remove the Must section of the query for Role Name, I get plenty of SearchResult records corresponding to John Smith, even those where John Smith is the second or third item in the Names collection.  However, as soon as I put in the section for Role Name, I get no results.  Am I going about querying these collections incorrectly?

I'm fairly new at using PlainElastic in C# so any advice or input is appreciated.

Thanks